# Why does this work with $(document).ready, but not when it's an anonymous function?

Tags: jquery

I'm starting to learn about the module design pattern, so I wrote some code to try things out. What am I doing wrong?

```
(function() {

    var test = {
    init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
        this.$button = $('button');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        this.$button.on('click', this.alertMsg);
    },
    alertMsg: function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    }

};

test.init();
})()
```

Comment: If you [read about what `$(document).ready` does](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), then you'll probably know.  *"A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. "* Also: *"The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place document.ready (or shorthand) inside module to wrap any actions, which require DOM to be fully loaded:

```js
(function() {

  var test = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$button = $('button');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$button.on('click', this.alertMsg);
    },
    alertMsg: function() {
      alert('Hello World');
    }

  };

  $(function() {
    test.init();
  });

})();
```

Remember that:

```js
$(function() {

});
```

is just $(document).ready shorthand.